# How in VTK I read a .stl file and write to a .mha file

Tags: multidimensional-array, stl, vtk

Some example how to do the task in the subject? Preferable in Python.

I suppose that .stl is 3D surface image and .mha are a 3D Volume (3 dimension array of pixels (compressed?)).
Some processing must be done in the middle (fill inside the surface).

Thanks,

Luis Gonçalves

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this example](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/vedo/examples/volumetric/mesh2volume.py) in `vedo`:

[image]

to save the volume add:
`write(v, 'vol.mhd')`

Comment: How to convert a variable of the class vtkplotter.volume.Volume to a volume in VTK and also how to convert vtkplotter.mesh.Mesh to a mesh in VTK? Thanks.

Comment: They already are!
try e.g. isinstance(vtkplotter.volume.Volume, vtk.vtkVolume) should give True
Mesh is a vtkActor. You can get the vtk.vtkPolydata object with mesh.polydata()

Comment: And if I want to convert the .stl to .mhd without volume fill? Only with the points of the surface. Are there some example?

Comment: MetaImage is only for volumetric data not polygonal data afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could try using VTK's PolyDataToImageDataStencil filter.  That's presumably what vtkplotter is using underneath.

Here's a Python example using vtkPolyDataToImageStencil:
https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/PolyData/PolyDataToImageDataStencil/

And here is the documentation for the class:
https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataToImageStencil.html