# How to convert .mha to .stl with python

Tags: python, 3d, vtk, itk

Know any method to convert from 3D volume to the surface mesh with python?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622555/how-in-vtk-i-read-a-stl-file-and-write-to-a-mha-file) linked to a [mesh to volume method](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/examples/volumetric/mesh2volume.py) but I couldn't find the opposite.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple algorithms for this: [marching cubes](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Modelling/MarchingCubes/), [flying edges](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/vtk/-/vtkFlyingEdges3D/python-vtkflyingedges3d-function-examples.html) and [cuberille](https://discourse.itk.org/t/how-to-convert-nifti-or-dicom-images-into-3d-mesh-by-using-itk/4265/6?u=dzenanz).